# save data from arraylist to shared preferences not working

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

i want to add the data from arraylist to sharedpreferences and retrieve the same.
     but it is not working. i am getting only one value which is the last value 
     not all values are retrieved from shared preferences. i am getting the values from 
     JSONArray first the added in the arraylist. 
     below is my code to save the data.

```
 JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(strServerResponse);
 JSONObject jsonObj = arr.getJSONObject(0);
 for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++) {
       pojo = new Pojo();
       JSONObject jobj2 = arr.getJSONObject(i);
       String tipoftheday = jobj2.optString("tipsoftheday");
       ArrayList<String> tii = new ArrayList<String>();
       tii.add(tipoftheday);
       SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("MyPref", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
       for (int i1 = 0; i1 < tii.size(); i1++) {
               editor.putString("tipoftheday", TextUtils.join(",", tii));
               editor.commit();
       }
 }
```

below is the code to retrieve data from shared preferences and using setter to set the d
     ata retrieved from shared preferences and adding it to list view adapter. i am not getting what is the mistake.

```
 SharedPreferences prefs=getSharedPreferences("MyPref", MODE_PRIVATE);
        String serialized = prefs.getString("tipoftheday", null);
        List<String> list = Arrays.asList(TextUtils.split(serialized,","));

for(int i=0; i < list.size(); i++){
            String ttt = list.get(i);
            pojo.setTip(ttt);
            tipsAdapter = new TipsAdapter(TipsActivity.this, tips);
            tips.add(pojo);
            listTips.setAdapter(tipsAdapter);
        }
```

How to save data in shared preferences? I am getting only one value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how to save data in shared prefernces. i am getting only one value.

Problem is not related to `SharedPreferences` it is related to data-source which is currently setting inside for-loop.

Set Adapter as:

```
    for(int i=0; i < list.size(); i++){
          String ttt = list.get(i);
          pojo.setTip(ttt);  
          tips.add(pojo);     
    }

tipsAdapter = new TipsAdapter(TipsActivity.this, tips);
listTips.setAdapter(tipsAdapter);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are losing your previous values because you are updating the same key inside your `SharedPreferences.Editor`. What you have to do in order to add more information afterwards is to first retreive your `String` value, then add your information and finally store all the info inside your `SharedPreferences.Editor`.

**EDIT**

I think it should be something like this, I have done it without any IDE or compiler, so it may have some syntax mistakes :)

```
 SharedPreferences prefs=getSharedPreferences("MyPref", MODE_PRIVATE);
 String serialized = prefs.getString("tipoftheday", null);
 List<String> list;
 if(serialized != null)
     list = Arrays.asList(TextUtils.split(serialized,","));
 list .add(tipoftheday);

 SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
   for (int i1 = 0; i1 < tii.size(); i1++) {
           editor.putString("tipoftheday", TextUtils.join(",", list));
           editor.apply(); // if you do not need the return value, apply is faster than commit
   }
```

Hope it helps

**EDIT 2**

Check also ρяσѕρєя K answer, he has spotted a different mistake you are making :)

Comment: Null pointer exception at  List<String> list = Arrays.asList(TextUtils.split(serialized,","));

Answer (score 0):

You are using two for loop when you are adding values to **SharedPreference**. Move out the inner loop and your code will be good to get you all values of list. Add some more line to it like below code:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++) {
           pojo = new Pojo();
           JSONObject jobj2 = arr.getJSONObject(i);
           String tipoftheday = jobj2.optString("tipsoftheday");
           ArrayList<String> tii = new ArrayList<String>();
           tii.add(tipoftheday);
  }



 for (int i1 = 0; i1 < tii.size(); i1++) {
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("MyPref", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
    SharedPreferences prefs=getSharedPreferences("MyPref", MODE_PRIVATE);
    StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
    stringBuffer = prefs.getString("tipoftheday", null).toString();
    editor.putString("tipoftheday", stringBuffer.append(stringBuffer +",", tii.get(i1).toString()));
    editor.commit();
 }
```

Comment: i am getting the error     cannot resolve method 'join(java.lang.String),(jav.lang.String)')

Comment: there is no `join` method in this code snippet, you are probably getting it elsewhere

Comment: **TextUtils.join** which i have updated now to **StringBuffer**

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

It will  work:

To store data:

```
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(strServerResponse);
    JSONObject jsonObj = arr.getJSONObject(0);
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++) 
    {
        pojo = new Pojo();
        JSONObject jobj2 = arr.getJSONObject(i);
        String tipoftheday = jobj2.optString("tipsoftheday");
        sb.append(tipoftheday).append(",");
    }
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("MyPref", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
    editor.putString("tipoftheday", sb).commit();
```

To retrieve data:

```
String[] strArr = getSharedPreferences("MyPref", MODE_PRIVATE).getString("tipsoftheday").split(",");
```